# User Profile Configuration - SharePoint [Me] keyword not working for one user

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, user-accounts

I am a SharePoint Developer (a relatively new one) and I have a mystery I have been trying to solve for exactly one user: we’ll call them User X.

**So here is the problem:**
My user cannot see their lists items for which they are the Initiator from their Dashboard which uses web parts and the [ME] keyword for filtering. User X is the only one having this problem.

Background:

Originally, Workflow A (2013) called Workflow B (2010) which is used to write to People/Group Fields for filtering purposes. In this case, User X experienced this problem. I have then consolidated all of workflow B into workflow A and User X still has the same problem. It is worth mentioning that this user has the same username as a previous user who is no longer with the company; however, I am assured they have a different ID in Active directory. 
I also tested this on another environment (our testing environment) and User X did indeed see her submitted items there. Whatever the problem is, it is specific to the production server. I went through the log data between the two and found the following log messages on Production but not on Testing:

```
Could not get token super user token, reverting to system account.  User is     -- GUID here –
```

And

```
Object Cache: The super user account utilized by the cache is not configured. This can increase the number of cache misses, which causes the page requests to consume unneccesary system resources.  To configure the account use the following command 'stsadm -o setproperty -propertyname portalsuperuseraccount -propertyvalue account -url webappurl'. The account should be any account that has Full Control access to the SharePoint databases but is not an application pool account.  Additional Data:  Current default super user account: SHAREPOINT\system -- GUID here –
```

And

SPJsonWebSecurityBaseTokenHandler: ValidateActorIsSelfIssuer! Issuer '00000005-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' is not self issuer

As well as lots of other fun SharePoint log things…

**My question is…** is there some sort of system configuration problem that could be causing this. Or what is the best way to handle this situation?